# circle inside of a box with visible circular area around circle with shadow css

Tags: html, css

How to make a box like this with css and html. a circle inside of a box with visible  circular area around circle with shadow and box also with shadow. the edges of the box when circle is inside also have radiud. how to create this with pure css and html.

here is my approch.

```css
  :root {
    --radius: clamp(20px, 4vw, 80px);
}

body {padding-top:100px; background:#f0f0f0;}


.circleBox {
  border-radius:10px;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
    background: radial-gradient( circle at 50% 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) clamp(20px, 14vw, 80px), #ffffff clamp(20px, 14vw, 80px), #ffffff 100% );
    fill: var(--White, #FFF);
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke: var(--Light-Grey, #FAFAFA);
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) inset;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10));
}


.circleInside {
  position:relative;
  top:-50px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:white;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) inset, 0px -1px 0px 1px #FFF inset, 0px -2px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) inset;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10));
}
```

```html
<div class='circleBox'>
  <div class="circleInside"></div>  
</div>
```

if some one can guide how to make red circle borders radius.

[image: here is the image]

Comment: here is my approch
https://codepen.io/mossawir/pen/RwddqPo

Comment: Best option here is a clip path or a mask

Comment: [Creating an inverted border-radius with CSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khjVPkO35F0) with Kevin Powell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to use `::before` and `::after` [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) as the left and right top borders:

```css
:root {
  --radius: clamp(20px, 4vw, 80px);
}

body {
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.circleBox {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: radial-gradient( circle at 50% 2%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) clamp(20px, 14vw, 80px), #ffffff clamp(20px, 14vw, 80px), #ffffff 100%);
  fill: var(--White, #FFF);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: var(--Light-Grey, #FAFAFA);
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) inset;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.circleInside {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) inset;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10));
}

.circleBox::before,
.circleBox::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  left: 1px;
  top: -6px;
  content: "";
  box-shadow: -0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) inset;
}

.circleBox::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circleBox">
  <div class="circleInside"></div>
</div>
```

I've also changed the shadows and background circle a bit.

Adjust the `width` and `top` properties of pseudo elements as needed.